# SSRS Date formatting and sorting

Tags: sorting, datetime, reporting-services, formatting

i'm having trouble on the formatting of my dates I have a report which has a date column and its coming up like

1/4/2016 4:08:03PM and I would like it to be 4/1/2016.

once I have done that I would like to sort it by the date range.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to sort it by the date range"?

Comment: I have added explanation on sorting. If "date range" is a calculated column, you just follow the steps. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format the dates, go to the "details" row and right-click on the text box. Go to **Text Box Properties...** -> **Number** -> **Category**. Select "Date" and choose "Custom" format. Provide "dd/MM/yyyy" in the text box that appears there.

[image]

Voila! Date has been formatted.

For sorting(which I am assuming is on a column in tablix), go to tablix properties and then to "Sorting". Click on "Add" and specify the column on which you want to sort and then mention the "Order"(Ascending or Descending).

Comment: I'm not getting a Asc or desc option only a-z which isn't working

Comment: A-Z is Ascending and Z-A is Descending. Its a character sort. That means for values 1, 2, 10, 24 sorting would be 1, 10, 2, 24.

Comment: format of date id now 04-01-2016 but with the A-Z sort on its still in a mixed up order.

Comment: Add an `order by` clause in the underlying SQL(assuming SQL data source)